# Create new photo album via the application

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, social-framework

I need some help with Facebook integration from the experts.
I'm working on an iOS 6 app using Social.framework for posting on Facebook.

```
-(IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        facebookController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [facebookController addImage:self.selectedImageView.image];
        [self presentViewController:facebookController animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

}

The problem is when  I upload the photo it goes to an album called iOS photos. Is it possible when I upload the photo, to be created automatically a new album with the name of my app and all the photos go there?

Comment: did u got the answer for this.. PLease help me @gkonstandas

Comment: Not yet, I will post it here when i find it